# Oracle SQL developer deleted rows without queries

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using oracle sql developer client on windows to connect to Oracle Database.

One regular day I got an email that my computer using SQL developer, has deleted ~400 rows from table with ~700 rows (not all of them).
Naturally I started investigating how and why this happened.
I examined all of the queries executed from my client (SQL History) and NONE of them (I am 100% sure about this) deletes anything from the table.

Also there are no triggers or any foreign keys related to this.

In the server logs we say the exact queries and they where one for each row, also they where very specific (obviously generated), the only way for this to happen is to manually delete row from the UI of the client. All 400+ queries were executed in the same second.

But to do so you need to go to the table select 400 rows and click delete.
I always use SQL queries to do things and never would have used the client to delete rows (atleast knowingly).

Other thing is if I somehow deleted the rows through the client I would have deleted all of them or one of them not a specific number of rows.

My question did someone had similar experience?
Can anyone guess how could you delete specific rows with some king of shortcut or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: what generated the email?  what did that program (or person) use to identify you or your computer specifically?  Trace back from there.

Comment: Do you trust your colleagues , your boss, janitors?

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak Haha, that was my first thought too. Thing is I did it some how without knowing.

tbone I don't know what software is used to gather logs. The email was from the db team. They had full log of all executed queries on the server.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if they identified your IP or just your login (by user).

Comment: ask them to show you the queries. the way the DELETEs are written will  help you identify how they were issues in the tool..and the exact time they were issued - your sqlhistory may exonerate you...somewhat. by the way, these rows got deleted SOMEHOW. You'd also would have had to COMMIT the rows being deleted - unless you were debugging/working on a stored procedure that did this? or you deleted rows from a VIEW that hit said table.